# ASP.NET MVC Razor Getting select option value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here's my code. Excuse me if I explain this wrong.

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field 
SupervisorID must be a number." data-val-required="The SupervisorID field is 
required." id="SupervisorID" name="SupervisorID"><option value="" 
disabled="disabled">Select Supervisor</option>
<option value="5" disabled="disabled">Tom</option>
<option value="6" disabled="disabled">John</option>
</select>
```

My question is how do I access the option value. I tried using

```
   $('select[option[value*='+$val+']]').removeAttribute
```

I just want to remove the attribute from the value selected.
$val is a value that I select in a checkbox and that selected value gets enabled in the select list. So when I check value 5 Tom will have his disabled attribute removed. But this doesn't seem to work. And I tried using:

```
document.getElementByID('SupervisorID').options[$val].removeAttribute('disabled');
```

But when the value is 5 or 6 and there's only 2 option there isn't a 5th or 6th value in the list. In this way when there's 2 values and I check the second one (John with the value 6) in the select list it selects the 6th value of the list, when there isn't one.

I would like to do this the first way, not with the options[$val] way, although any help is appreciated.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done using jquery.

```js
 $('select option:selected').removeAttr('disabled');
   $(".chk").on("change",function(){

     if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $('select option[value="' + $(this).attr('value')+ '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field 
SupervisorID must be a number." data-val-required="The SupervisorID field is 
required." id="SupervisorID" name="SupervisorID">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Supervisor</option>
<option value="5" disabled="disabled">Tom</option>
<option value="6" disabled="disabled">John</option>
</select>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="5"  />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="6"  />
```